# A recurrence relation departed in odd and even cases

Tags: recurrence-relations

During my investigation on order of monomials (came from an $I$-adic topology on $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$) I encounter the recurrence relation
$$c_{2n+1}=n^2+c_{n+1},\\ c_{2n}=n^2-n+1+c_n.$$
Unfortunately, I have no idea, how to proceed, well I never face some thing like that before.

Any hints or clues is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the first few values on OEIS?

Comment: @saulspatz: the sequence is: $$1,2,3,5,7,10,14,18,23,\ldots$$

Comment: Solve it in terms of the binary representation of $n$. Start from the easy case of $n$ a power of $2$.

Comment: Does any of [these](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C10%2C14%2C18%2C23&language=english&go=Search) look right?

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you. The last one exactly is what I want. Just to be sure, Is   G.f. A(x) = (1-x+x^2)/(1-x)^3 - x*[Sum_{n>=0} x^(n + 2^n)]/(1-x)^2 . the generating function?

Comment: That's what I would think, but I can't say I know for sure.